# Kivy Drag Behavior Labels and Rectangles

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am having trouble with one particular idea:

I have created a rectangle that I am able to drag using the Drag Behavior in Kivy. Although, I want the rectangle to be dragged only left/right and fix the Y position.

How can I accomplish this? I have tried multiple combinations, looked for this particular issue online, and I even checked the source code but I could not put it together. Any help is very much appreciated thank you!

**Here is the code below:**

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
<DragLabel>:
    # Define the properties for the DragLabel
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0

FloatLayout:
    # Define the root widget
    DragLabel:
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.2
        text: 'Drag me'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .6, .6, .6
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size 
'''

class DragLabel(DragBehavior, Label):
    pass

class RectangleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        object = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return object

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RectangleApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use a Label with the DragBehaviour, then you have to redefine the `on_touch_up`, `on_touch_down` and `on_touch_move` of your Label

But a better and simpler way to achieve this is to use a `ScatterLayout` and disable the translation on the y axis:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    # Define the root widget
    ScatterLayout:
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.2
        do_translation_y: False
        Label:
            size_hint: 1.0, 1
            text: 'Drag me'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: .6, .6, .6
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size 
'''

class RectangleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        object = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return object

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RectangleApp().run()
```

Comment: You’ve done it again!! You are so helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Box_layout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Box_layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (.50,.50)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        for  x in range(5):
           DragButton.text=str(x)
           self.add_widget(DragButton())

class DragButton(DragBehavior, Button):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
       super(DragButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.drag_rect_width = 1366
       self.drag_rect_height = 768
       self.drag_timeout = 10000000
       self.drag_distance = 0
       print(self.height, self.width)
```

This is another example of DragBehavior